# How do you build algorithms to optimize high scores on games

Tags: python, algorithm, game-physics

My favorite app I have ever played is drop7, a puzzle game. I have linked the wikipedia page if you're not familiar with it

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drop7

Since I've started playing this game Ive just been trying to get high scores in their blitz round because it's a quick game. I want to write a script, preferably in Python, where I can simulate this game. I then want to find Out some strategies that help you get higher scores or if I can learn about optimizing a game like drop 7.

I'm not sure where to start and I would like your help. I know how to code in Python, but not terribly well, classes confuse me a bit so I stick to just functions.

Thank you for your insight

Comment: Start looking into 2D Lists and just start playing around with a simple version and then build up. You follow your goals. I started coding a year ago, and it is only by practice,practice and more practice you get better. Classes are tricky to get the hang of, but you really can take your code to the next level when you can get the hang of them. Quick Tip: when learning about functions, just focus on the __init__ and simple functions.